# How do you fix repetitive javascript code within multiple functions?

Tags: javascript

This is my first time using stack overflow. I'm working on making a journal web application as a personal project.

So I have 2 functions, one function adds a journal entry (which stores in localStorage) and the other gets the journal entry from the localStorage. Both functions create DOM elements.

Here's the first function:

```js
function addJournalEntry(event) {
    if(entryTitle.value === '' && entryText.value === '') {
        alert('Please enter fields')
    } else {
        // Create an anchor tag
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        // Creates a div element
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        // Create title
        var title = document.createElement('h5');
        // Create a date (current)
        var dateLog = document.createElement('small');
        // Create text
        var text = document.createElement('p');
        // Create edit button
        var editLink = document.createElement('a');
        editLink.id = 'edit-button';
        editLink.innerHTML = '<i class="icon ion-compose"></i>';
        // Create delete button
        var deleteLink = document.createElement('a');
        deleteLink.id = 'delete-button';
        deleteLink.innerHTML = '<i class="icon ion-trash-a"></i>';

        // Display input values
        title.textContent = entryTitle.value;
        dateLog.textContent = formatDate();
        text.textContent = entryText.value;

        // Append elements in the DOM
        container.appendChild(title);
        container.appendChild(dateLog);
        listItem.appendChild(container);
        listItem.appendChild(text);
        listItem.appendChild(editLink);
        listItem.appendChild(deleteLink);
        entryList.appendChild(listItem);

        event.preventDefault();

        // Store locally
        storeDataLocally(entryTitle.value, formatDate(), entryText.value);

        // Empty form fields
        entryTitle.value = '';
        entryText.value = '';
    }
}
```

Here's the second function:

```js
function getLocalData() {
    var dataArray;

    // Checks if the journalEntry is in local storage. If not, create an array.
    if(localStorage.getItem('journalEntry') === null) {
        dataArray = [];
    } else {
        dataArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('journalEntry'));
    }

    dataArray.forEach(function(data) {
        // Create an anchor tag
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        // Creates a div element
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        // Create title
        var title = document.createElement('h5');
        // Create a date (current)
        var dateLog = document.createElement('small');
        // Create text
        var text = document.createElement('p');
        // Create edit button
        var editLink = document.createElement('a');
        editLink.id = 'edit-button';
        editLink.innerHTML = '<i class="icon ion-compose"></i>';
        // Create delete button
        var deleteLink = document.createElement('a');
        deleteLink.id = 'delete-button';
        deleteLink.innerHTML = '<i class="icon ion-trash-a"></i>';

        // Diplay data values
        title.textContent = data.title;
        dateLog.textContent = data.date;
        text.textContent = data.text;

        // Append elements in the DOM
        container.appendChild(title);
        container.appendChild(dateLog);
        listItem.appendChild(container);
        listItem.appendChild(text);
        listItem.appendChild(editLink);
        listItem.appendChild(deleteLink);
        entryList.appendChild(listItem);
    });
}
```

Right now I'm having an issue with repetitiveness and I was wondering how to fix it and make it more modular? Thank you!

Comment: Put the repetitive code in a named function and call it from both places. This is one of the most basic techniques in programming.

Comment: Until you're able to identify the duplicate part easily unassisted, I've found sticking the two codes in a "text difference finder" (google one) to help highlight what parts differ and what's the same. Make the same parts the body of a third function, and make the different parts the parameters of the function. Practice this to death, because you'll need this ability a lot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic extraction to a function: define a function (call it something like 'renderItem', or something more specific) and take all the code that matches in the two functions and move it into there. Then call that function in both  of your other functions. Easy-peasy.

If there are any lines that are almost the same, extract the parts that are different to variable, and then make those variable arguments to the function.

Sometimes you have code in-between the parts that are the same, but you cannot really make that a variable. In these cases you have a few options:

1. extract two smaller methods, and call them before and after the the different sections
2. extract a function for each different section of code, and pass it (without calling it) to the extracted function as an argument. This is called a callback.

Examples:

```
function foo(…){
  …
  <same part 1>

  <different part>

  <same part 2>
  …
}
```

Method 1:

```
function baz1(){ <same part 1> }
function baz2(){ <same part 2> }
function foo(…) {
  …
  baz1()
  <different part>
  baz2()
  …
}
```

Method 2:

```
function baz(callback){
  <same part 1>

  callback()

  <same part 2>
}
function foo(…){
  …
  baz(function() {
    <different part>
  })
  …
}
```

Comment: So if I were to create a function containing the similar code, would there be issues with accessing them due to variable scoping?

Comment: Yes, any variable you create inside a function block are only accessible to code written inside that function block. But usually that is what you want. If you need access to variables created before the function is called, pass them in as arguments. If you need access to variables the function makes, return them from the function. (You can use an object to return multiple variables if needed)

Comment: Ohhh... I see... So in my case where most of the variables are being created, I will just have to return each and every single variable within that function? That sounds pretty tedious...

Comment: only if you need to access those variables outside your function. You should try to structure your code so that each function deals with as few things as possible. If you have functions the deal with a lot of variables coming in or going out, that's usually a sign to split it to multiple functions. If you need variables in multiple functions, you probably want to create them in outside the function, and pass them in as arguments.